# How to send NTLM authenticated post request using jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, sharepoint-2013, ntlm

I am making rest api calls to Sharepoint 2013 using Java. How can I connect to the sharepoint 2013 using jersey rest client?

Note: currently I am using apache http components and `NTCredentials` class

```
Credentials credentials=new NTCredentials(username, password, workstation, domain);
AuthScope authScope=new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY);
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(authScope,credentials);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
```

How to adopt this to Jersey framework?

Comment: Please supply any code where you have attempted to create a solution, provide evidence that you have done some researched or understand the basic principles of what you're trying to achieve. People will be more able to help knowing a bit more about what you're trying to do, what you have tried, what you have read. The versions of your libraries and application structure/frameworks will also help.

Comment: @DanielTung I have added my work

Answer (score 6):

The following code executes an NTLM authenticated HTTP GET request that using Jersey:

```
public Response executeRestGet(String user, String pass) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(prepareClientConfig(user, pass));
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost/").path("site/_api/xxxxx");
    return target.request(HTTP_ACCEPT_JSON).get();
}

private ClientConfig prepareClientConfig(String user, String pass) {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    //make sure to supply all 4 arguments to the  NTCredentials constructor
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials(user, pass, null, null));

    clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER, credentialsProvider);
    clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
    return clientConfig;
}
```

Please note that this approach requires: `jersey-apache-connector`. Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried the suggested solution but if I do a post of the form: client.target(...).request().post(...) 
no "Authorization" header gets attached to my request. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just discovered that one has to be careful about what versions of the different libraries are on the classpath. At the moment, NTLM breaks if I depend on Tika (a seemingly unrelated library) that happens to depend on the httpclient-library. In my case I suspect that the "correct" version is swapped out by gradles dependency-resolution.