# NTLM authentication works with curl, but not from Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, curl, jersey, ntlm

I try to connect to application which is deployed on Windows Server.
I uses NTLM. I'm using Ubuntu and Java8.

I'm getting `HTTP 401` code, but only if I try to connect
from my Java application. Curl request with exactly the same
authentication details works ok, I'm getting `HTTP 200`:

```
curl -v -L --ntlm -u 'myuser\mydomain:mypass' 'http://myip/api/element/151
```

This is my Java code
(I simplified it a bit, to include only problem-related stuff):

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
...
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheClientProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnectorProvider;
...
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestEntityProcessing;
...

class MyConnector {

    private final Client client;
    ...

    protected ClientConfig prepareClientConfig() {
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.property(ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION, true);
        config.property(ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, true);
        config.property(ClientProperties.REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING, RequestEntityProcessing.BUFFERED);

        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials("myuser", "mypassword",
                "mydomain", "mydomain"));

        config.property(ApacheClientProperties.CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER, credentialsProvider);
        config.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());

        return config;
    }

    ...

    MyConnector(...) {

    ...
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient(prepareClientConfig());

    }


    protected String getDocString(...) throws MyException {

        WebTarget target = client.target("http://myipi/api").path("element/151");

        Invocation.Builder temp = target.request();
        Response response = target.request().get();

        if (response.getStatus() == Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
            String docString = response.readEntity(String.class);

            return docString;
        }

        throw new MyException("Couldn't obtain doc. HTTP error code: " + response.getStatus());
    }

    ...
}
```

It takes 5-15 (!) minutes to invoke the `getDocString` function.
I also believe that application eats unusually large amount of RAM,
although no other function is run simultaneously (the program is not parallelised).
Then I get `HTTP 401` code.

I had some cases when my Java application worked. The story was:

1. my application worked without NTLM
2. my colleagues added NTLM to their app, I adjusted code, my app got `401`, my curl request got `401`
3. I upgraded from `Ubuntu 14 LTS` to `Ubuntu 16.0.2 LTS`, my app got `200`, curl got `200`
4. I gave out the server on which the setup worked (I don't have it any more)
5. I set up a new server, again with `Ubuntu 16.0.2 LTS`, my app got `401`, curl got `200`
6. I upgraded to `Ubuntu 17.04` (non-LTS), my app got `200` once, but I cannot
   reproduce it, now exactly the same request gets `401`, curl gets `200`

I'm aware of this question:
[How to send NTLM authenticated post request using jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075951/how-to-send-ntlm-authenticated-post-request-using-jersey)
I used the code and it allowed my app to work in combination with server upgrade (at point `3.`).
But I don't know how to make it work again.

I used mitmproxy to debug the request, the output looks like this
(I obscured the `Authorization`/`WWW-Authenticate` fields):

```
Proxy server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080
127.0.0.1:39622: clientconnect
127.0.0.1:39622: request
  -> Request(GET /api/element/151)
127.0.0.1:39622: serverconnect
  -> myip:80
127.0.0.1:39622: response
  -> Response(401 Unauthorized, text/html, 1.26k)
127.0.0.1:39622: GET http://myip/api/element/151
    User-Agent: Jersey/2.26-b03 (Apache HttpClient 4.5.3)
    Host: myip
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
 << 401 Unauthorized 1.26k
    Content-Type: text/html
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
    WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 13:38:36 GMT
    Content-Length: 1293
127.0.0.1:39622: request
  -> Request(GET /api/element/151)
127.0.0.1:39622: response
  -> Response(401 Unauthorized, text/html; charset=us-ascii, 341b)
127.0.0.1:39622: GET http://myip/api/element/151
    User-Agent: Jersey/2.26-b03 (Apache HttpClient 4.5.3)
    Host: myip
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    Authorization: NTLM TlRAAA==
 << 401 Unauthorized 341b
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
    Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
    WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRAAABBBBBBAAA==
    Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 13:38:36 GMT
    Content-Length: 341
127.0.0.1:39622: request
  -> Request(GET /api/element/151)
127.0.0.1:39622: server communication error: TcpDisconnect('[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer',)
127.0.0.1:39622: serverdisconnect
  -> myip:80
127.0.0.1:39622: serverconnect
  -> myip:80
127.0.0.1:39622: response
  -> Response(401 Unauthorized, text/html, 1.26k)
127.0.0.1:39622: GET http://myip/api/element/151
    User-Agent: Jersey/2.26-b03 (Apache HttpClient 4.5.3)
    Host: myip
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    Authorization: NTLM TlRAAABBBDDDAAA==
 << 401 Unauthorized 1.26k
    Content-Type: text/html
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
    WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 13:44:35 GMT
    Content-Length: 1293
127.0.0.1:39622: serverdisconnect
  -> myip:80
127.0.0.1:39622: clientdisconnect
```

I will be very grateful for any remarks on this.

**Update:** I also tried Debian8 and Debian9. The result is the same. I got `401` ad Debian8, updated to Debian9, got `200` once and then continuously `401` (for the exactly same request).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using JCIFS library instead of default NTLM authentication from HttpClient. You can see the example on the Apache page:
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/ntlm.html

The problem is that I couldn't find a way to make it compatible with Jersey. Jersey uses `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` and I didn't know how to update the AuthScheme of it (there's no method to set it). So I switched to `org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient` and rewrote whole application to use raw HttpClient methods.